# Compute the result of an equation, but with selectable operator precedence

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

Forget BIDMAS! Write a program that takes an equation *and* an operator precedence order, and prints the result.

Example input format:

```
1.2+3.4*5.6/7.8-9.0 */+-
```

Rules & guidelines:

- The only operators that are defined are addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), and division (/). No parentheses, no exponentiation.
- Associativity is always left-to-right. For example, `10/4/2` is to be interpreted as `(10/4)/2` with a result of 1.25, rather than `10/(4/2)`.
- The input format is as follows:

  - An equation, followed by a space, followed by the operator precedence specification (or two string arguments, one for the equation and the other for the precedence).
  - The equation comprises base-10 decimal numbers separated by operators, with no spaces. Integer values do not have to contain a period character, i.e. both `5` and `5.0` are to be accepted values.
  - For simplicity, negative numbers may not be included in the input, e.g. `6/3` is valid but `6/-3` is not. Input also may not contain a leading or trailing operator, so `-6/3` isn't considered valid, nor is `6-3+`.
  - The precedence specification string is always 4 characters long and always contains the characters `+`, `-`, `/`, and `*` once each. Precedence is read as left-to-right, e.g. `*/+-` specifies multiplication with the highest precedence, division next, then addition, and finally subtraction. **EDIT:** It is acceptable to take the precedence string in reverse order (lowest to highest) as long as you specify this in your answer.
- Input is a string to be taken via command line arguments, STDIN, or the default input format in programming languages that do not support these input methods.
- You are free to assume that the given input will be in the correct format.
- Output is via STDOUT or your language's normal output method.
- The printed result should be in base-10 decimal.
- Results must be computed to at least 4 decimal points of accuracy when compared to a correct implementation that uses double precision (64-bit) floating point arithmetic. This degree of freedom is designed to allow for the use of fixed-point arithmetic in languages that have no floating-point support.
- Divide by zero, overflow, and underflow are undefined behaviour. Your code is free to assume that no inputs will be given that will trigger these cases.
- You may not call out to any external services (e.g. Wolfram Alpha)
- You may not call out to any programs whose primary function is to solve these types of problems.

Test cases:

1. `6.3*7.8` followed by any operator precedence specification prints 49.14
2. `2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1 */+-` is parsed as `((2.2*3.3)+(9.9/8.8))-1.1` and should print 7.285
3. `2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1 +*/-` is parsed as `((2.2*(3.3+9.9))/8.8)-1.1` and should print 2.2
4. `10/2+5-1 +-/*` is parsed as `10/((2+5)-1)` and the printed result should be 1.6666666...
5. `2147480/90+10*5 +/-*` is parsed as `(2147480/(90+10))*5` and the printed result should be 107374
6. `3*55-5/8/4+1 -/+*` is parsed as `3*((((55-5)/8)/4)+1)` should print 7.6875
7. An input containing one thousand instances of the number `1.015` separated by multiplier operators (i.e. the expanded multiplicative form of `1.015^1000`), followed by any operated precedence specification, should print a number within 0.0001 of 2924436.8604.

Code golf, so shortest code wins.

Comment: "BIDMAS" is "PEMDAS" in the US because why wouldn't it be?

Comment: It's also taught as "BODMAS" in some UK schools (Brackets Orders).

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/131567/operator-precedence-how-wrong-can-i-be).

Comment: [Also related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/61463/58563).

Comment: The fact that you can't have two operators have the same precedence (like `*/` and `+-` in normal math) saddens me :( oh well :P

Comment: Can I take the operator precedence in reverse order?

Comment: Can I take 5 arguments to a function as the expression and then the 4 operators in their order of precedence?

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Input is a string in the specified format only.

Comment: @Polynomial [*cough*](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/8077#8077)

Comment: @NieDzejkob In this case I think the input format is flexible enough, and HyperNeutrino's request to allow 5 arguments to a function as the expression removes a lot of the parsing work that makes this challenge interesting. Operator precedence in reverse order is acceptable, though, now that I think about it more.

Comment: @Polynomial I also think that five arguments is too much, but allowing two strings, one for the formula and one for the operators, seems reasonable. Splitting at white space is probably not the interesting part of parsing.

Comment: @Laikoni Also acceptable. Edited to reflect.

Comment: Can intermediate results be negative? For example, is something like ```5-8+4 -+/*``` (= ```-3+4``` = ```1```) a possible input to the program?

Comment: @Polynomial The parsing of I/O is NOT the interesting part of challenges.

Comment: @JonathanS. Yes

Comment: The parsing work does not make the challenge interesting. The parsing methods should be completely answerer-defined IMO. It's the actual *challenge*, not the I/O, that makes the challenge interesting.

Comment: I think your profile picture perfectly relates how most of us feel about the I/O :P   (no offense meant, just a jest)

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES6), 94 bytes

Not particularly short, but fun. Adding parentheses all over the place...

```js
s=>([e,o]=s.split` `,[...o].map(x=>e=e.split(x).join((a+=')')+x+(b+='(')),a=b=''),eval(b+e+a))
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

s=>([e,o]=s.split` `,[...o].map(x=>e=e.split(x).join((a+=')')+x+(b+='(')),a=b=''),eval(b+e+a))

console.log(f("6.3*7.8 +-*/"))              // 49.14
console.log(f("2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1 */+-"))  // 7.285
console.log(f("2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1 +*/-"))  // 2.2
console.log(f("10/2+5-1 +-/*"))             // 1.6666
console.log(f("2147480/90+10*5 +/-*"))      // 107374
console.log(f("3*55-5/8/4+1 -/+*"))         // 7.6875
```

#### Historical note

A similar method was used in early FORTRAN compilers. Here is a [link from archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_computersA_13990695/196212#page/n9/mode/2up) to a relevant article written by [Donald E. Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth) in a 1962 book called *Computers and automation*.

#### Examples

Let's consider the expression `2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1`.

With operator precedence `*/+-`, it will expand to:

```
((((2.2)*(3.3)))+(((9.9))/((8.8))))-((((1.1))))
```

With operator precedence `+*/-`, it will now expand to:

```
((((2.2))*((3.3)+(9.9)))/(((8.8))))-((((1.1))))
```

Removing all redundant parentheses, we get:

```
((2.2*3.3)+(9.9/8.8))-1.1 = 7.285
```

and:

```
((2.2*(3.3+9.9))/8.8)-1.1 = 2.2
```

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>174</s> 133 bytes

Saved 41 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

```js
i=>([e,o]=i.split` `,e=e.split(/([+*/-])/),[...o].map(x=>{while(~(b=e.indexOf(x)))e.splice(--b,3,eval(e.slice(b,b+3).join``))}),e[0])
```

First golf! This is probably terribly unoptimized.

#### Ungolfed:

```js
f = input => {
    [equation, output] = input.split(" ");
    equation = equation.split(/([+*/-])/);
    [...output].map(x => {
        while (~(b = equation.indexOf(x))) {
            equation.splice(--b, 3, eval(equation.slice(b, b + 3).join("")));
        }
    });
    return equation[0];
};
```

This splits the input equation into tokens of numbers and operators, then iterates through operators in the specified order and collapses pairs of numbers using `eval()` until there's only one left.

JavaScript rounding error trash means that test case 3 results in `2.1999...` instead of `2.2`. I'm not sure if that disqualifies this answer, but oh well.

#### Test cases:

```js
f=i=>([e,o]=i.split` `,e=e.split(/([+*/-])/),[...o].map(x=>{while(~(b=e.indexOf(x)))e.splice(--b,3,eval(e.slice(b,b+3).join``))}),e[0])

console.log(f("6.3*7.8 +-/*"));
console.log(f("2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1 */+-"));
console.log(f("2.2*3.3+9.9/8.8-1.1 +*/-"));
console.log(f("10/2+5-1 +-/*"));
console.log(f("2147480/90+10*5 +/-*"));
console.log(f("3*55-5/8/4+1 -/+*"));
console.log(f((new Array(1000)).fill("1.015").join("*") + " +-*/"));
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Some quick wins: Use `map` instead of `forEach`. Use destructuring assignment `[e,o]=i.split` and then use `e` and `o` instead of `a[0]` and `a[1]`.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG, nice first solution.

Comment: You may also replace `e.replace(/[+\-*/]/g," $& ").split\` \` ` with `e.split(/([+*/-])/)` (splitting while capturing the separators).

Comment: @Arnauld Ooh, that's neat. Why does putting the character set in a capture group retain the separators?

Comment: Quoting [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.split): _If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array._

Answer (score 4):

### JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

```
f=(s,[o,...a])=>eval(o?s.split(o).map(e=>f(e,a)).join(o):s)
```

Port of my golf of @HyperNeutrino's Python answer. Takes lowest precedence first.

Comment: ...wow, so much cleaner than my lousy attempt...

Comment: that's amazing...

Comment: @edc65 Oops, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 77 bytes

```python
f=lambda a,b:eval(b and b[0].join(str(f(A,b[1:]))for A in a.split(b[0]))or a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpLCsMgEADQqwyuZhrzsaWbQBY5R8hiJJVa7ChGCj29SbaPl/7lHeVRq5sCf@3GwNqOrx8HtMCygV2GtftEL7iXjA5nbRczrkQuZpjBC3C3p@ALXpPoVKaaspdybmWG/t48W6M0qFvfNoqoHg)

-23 bytes thanks to Neil (takes operator precedence in reverse)
-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: 78 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvNCgIhEADgVxk8Oa37Y9FlocM@x7KHGVKaMBWVoKe36P59@dMeKV5697dAL74TkOHVvSlo3pdjeiaJuraivd4M73Y9EH0qsIFEoKnmIO0vEcUDgwvVAWHPRWL7JWWX@TxcR6sMqNM8DgqxfwE "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcpLCsMgEADQqwyuZhrzsaWbQBY5R8hiJJVa7ChGCj29SbaPl/7lHeVRq5sCf@3GwNqOrx8HtMCygV2GtftEL7iXjA5nbRczrkQuZpjBC3C3p@ALXpPoVKaaspdybmWG/t48W6M0qFvfNoqoHg)

Comment: @edc65 pointed out in a comment on my answer that I forgot to make it clear that my golf takes the precedence string in reverse.

Comment: @Neil Ah yes, I didn't notice, thanks. I'll edit my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 87 bytes

```
x=>y=>eval((f=b=>a=>b?"(#{e.join(map(f(b[to-1]),a.split(e=b[-1])))})":a)(y)(x)).evalf()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxBCsIwEAXQu4ybP9akRnAjTDxIcZFAUiK1CTVIi3j2SLdv8cqSa57bKG0Vu4kNHzcBUbxYJ9bfCYdv0M@cZrxcQYQfalbmwSen32VKFUH8sAPzj@nmGBtjZdb7FMGtLGmuGEHm3F@6qzLEoE71R2Jufw)

+19 bytes to accommodate for the unnecessarily restrictive output format. seriously? the restriction is actually making the answers *less* accurate because now instead of precise fractional output it's giving inaccurate IEEE floating points... think about it...

Comment: Your "try it online" sample is outputting the result as a fraction rather than a decimal.

Comment: @Polynomial Does that really matter? If so, I can change it, but that's a feature of the language; making me change it would be considered cumbersome I/O format which is highly discouraged but up to you.

Comment: I think normally it'd be a cumbersome I/O format in a different problem space, but in this case the question is specifically asking you to solve the numerical result of a formula, and outputting a different formula (which is what a fraction ultimately is) isn't really achieving that. Otherwise one could arguably just print the input for any case `^[0-9\.]+/[0-9\.]+$`.

Comment: @Polynomial I disagree, a fraction is a numeric format, like a decimal expansion. A special case avoiding any work for the very special case `a/b` would be worthles for all others

Comment: @Polynomial I believe that according to the meta post [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9263/which-number-formats-are-acceptable-in-output/9264#9264) that fractions are normally considered valid numeric output.

Comment: @Potato44 In the general case, yes, but since this challenge is explicitly about evaluating such expressions in the first place I do not agree that is an appropriate output format. If the decimal-only restriction takes the enjoyment out of the challenge for you, then I suggest just skipping this one.

Comment: @Polynomial I do believe it takes the enjoyment out of this challenge for this answer because now the Proton golfing tricks which were designed specifically to beat Python no longer work. -1 from me for now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
ṣ⁹ḊṪ¤ñ€⁹Ṗ¤j⁹ḊṪ¤ŒVµ¹⁹?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPGnc@3NH1cOeqQ0sOb3zUtAbE3znt0JIsJImjk8IObT20Eyhi////fyUjPSMtYz1jbUs9S30LPQtdQz1Dpf9K2lr6ukoA)

## Explanation

```
ṣ⁹ḊṪ¤ñ€⁹Ṗ¤j⁹ḊṪ¤ŒVµ¹⁹?  Main Link
                    ?  Ternary:
                   ⁹   If the right argument is truthy:
ṣ                      Split it by
  ḊṪ                   The last element of
 ⁹  ¤                  The right argument
      €                For each element
     ñ                 Call the next link as a dyad (wraps around so this calls the current link as a dyad)
       ⁹Ṗ¤             With right argument as `right_argument[:-1]`
          j            Join with
            ḊṪ         The last element of
           ⁹  ¤        The right argument
               ŒV      Evaluate as Python code
                 µ     Start a new monadic chain. If the right argument is falsy:
                  ¹    Identity: Return the left argument unmodified
```

Comment: Is this 21 bytes or 21 UTF-8 characters? Is Jelly one of those languages with a custom codepage to reduce things down to an 8-bit space?

Comment: @Polynomial Jelly is one of those languages.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 64 + 1 (`-p`) = 65 bytes

```perl
s/ .*//;for$i(map"\\$_",$&=~/./g){s/[\d.]*$i[0-9.]*/$&/ee&&redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZBCsIwEAXQq5QyBE2b/BQdsIhH8ASNiNAogWpC4k706I6@1cuhLCxS0VgN7K@pUFzdL7n1ns5tT@rwgcVt/aqY/GxPmuLkzPgPSCEEpUqY01tko5kNY4dtNzQGnf6m/IzpUcUc2brBick/)

Comment: `0-9`  can be replaced with `\d`, however seems it's missing a loop to handle multiple instance of an operator for example `3*55-5/8/4+1 -/+*`

Comment: You're right.  It was only handling the first instance of each operator.

Comment: `\Q$i\E` to avoid `map"\\$_"`

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 96 bytes

```
f=(o,s)=>o?f(o.slice(s!=(s=s.replace(eval(['/','\\'+o[0],'/'].join`(\\d+\\.?\\d*)`),eval))),s):s
```

A non-recursive attempt was first made for this technique, but it came up at 101:

```
(s,o)=>[...o].map(x=>[...s].map(_=>s=s.replace(eval(['/','\\'+x,'/'].join`(\\d+\\.?\\d*)`),eval)))&&s
```

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 167 bytes

```
(defn f [i O](eval(read-string(or(first(filter some?(for[o O](let[[x y](clojure.string/split i(re-pattern(str \\ o))2)](when y(str" ("o\ (f x O)\ (f y O)")"))))))i))))
```

Whoa, long function names strike again! Operation precedence `O` is taken in "reverse" order.

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc) , 276 bytes

```
A,B,u,i,j,k;double g(){double a,b,f[1000];char o[999],p[5];for(i=k=0;o[i++]^32&&scanf("%lf%c",&f[i],&o[i]););for(gets(p);k<4;k++)for(A=B=0;B<i;A=B){for(;!f[B++]&&i/B;);if(A&&o[--A]==p[k])u=p[k],a=f[A],b=f[--B],f[B]=u^42?u^43?u^45?a/b:a-b:a+b:a*b,f[A]=0,o[A]=o[B++];}a=f[i-1];}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##7dDNbqMwEADgO0/BRirCP4NtfhpYF1XwGqwrERpSl2yI0kaqFOXZs0O6x73tdQ7@ZhhrxjYD7IbhdmtkK8/Sy3c52df5vNlvw13MLn/TXm7k2BmttbPDW38K566qKiePXeHsOJ9iX0@1tnPnhXAvWRpFH0N/GOPVw358GFYyGjvvZIT7jll279htPz/iI7PTU24nIdhSa@oWp7RP3mLGLkvJ/hi7FodGkVcttvoxbiIcBNC4uj52k2Pne5B9PXaNkxsMAK3D@7auPr/k6TOSLRTPvdr87AGXwMWXN@EULeclzPdz7HWZ48Fgdvvd@0P8fQ9/@Ay/6rX9ArDsEhxPWPh@36/DSuKvYja4Xm@PScbXSRkqATxIk5RnSSaqpFJlUoJJTMhx558bgisIjFapKAC/QGG/ydd5qVWlhdG8CIXCoRkvCihUqXJhQlCCBybRpuAkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSZIkSf6HoQCu/gA)

[Slightly longer solution using NAN](https://tio.run/##7dDLjpswFAbgvZ8CpRoEvmCbSwN16AgeYF6AeiSgQ@IyAZSLNFKVZ08PmS676/Ys/HE4xj@2e7Hv@/v9izsu8@myO7aXQ3T4Tipe8yt3/Bcfzc/52r2/efsg/E3@1i3v@NBopZQ1pD@0J29uiqKwfGky6AzzKXDlWCozN44x@5rEvn/u22kINk/vw1O/4f7QOMt9mLehCT@X7N8u52AJzbhLzchY@GhWZQ059c4ZqGAHa8@489ROwdDUEB76vpP1muGGoPIhUojKluXSjDYk18eTt@XQVJZ38BCitpzAWlteX9P4GUhWsudWdt9aAYPBoN36EQS9VC98Xov58TtDbmRNc0Kv9f3Yuglu5nHk6eJ9lFvzIYSBnS4naHye@Me04XB/sMfb7f41Sug2yj3JBCVxFNMkSlgRFTKPcqEj7VGY@ecEo1IQrWTMMgFvQsJ6nW7TXMlCMa1o5jEJoQnNMpHJXKZMe0IySnSkdEZRFEVRFEVRFEVRFEVRFEVRFP0PPSao/AM)